# How to set data in firebase realtime database with ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use firebase realtime database with an ASP.NET MVC app, and I searched through the internet and pretty much found no recourses even in the firebase website, my first question is how to set data without generating a key every time I want add some data.

```
var currentUserLogin = new LoginData() { TimestampUtc = currentLoginTime };
var firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("yourFirebaseProjectUrl");
var result = await firebaseClient
                       .Child("Users/" + userId + "/Logins")
                       .PostAsync(currentUserLogin, false);
```

This code generates a key every single time, I added `false` as a second parameter as for not to generate a key but it doesn't seem to work, my second question is where can I find resources related to the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the client you are using is a wrapper around Firebase's REST API, which interprets a `POST` request as a request to add the data as a new child node.

If you want to write the data to the exact path you specify, use a `PUT` request, so in your C# code that'd be `PutAsync`.

Comment: I tried then I got this error: "Error CS0815 Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable"

Comment: If I look at the [implementation of `PutAsync`](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/e7e628af78fd9f1655762911890766d048a3bf46/src/Firebase/Query/QueryExtensions.cs#L210) it doesn't return a value, so you can't assign that to a variable with `var result = `.